# Deserializing With Dill on Remote Pyro5 Object Yields Error

Tags: dill, pyro4

So I'm trying to have a remote Pyro5 object receive serialized arbitrary functions to execute them. The remote objects are run on a separate machine, registered on a Pyro5 name-server.

The built in serializer (serpent) in Pyro5 does not support function serialization, so I manually serialize the function with Dill, yielding a bytes type, which I send over when calling the remote object through Pyro5. I subsequently de-serialize the function on the remote-side, which yields the error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'Annotated' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py)

I've tested to implement a separate function which sends the serialized data back to the client from the remote object, where I subsequently de-serialized the data into a function, successfully. This implies that using Dill on the remote end, as opposed to Pyro5, is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `dill` author. It would help to know what versions of python, `dill`, etc you are using -- both on the local and remote machines.  However, I'm going to guess that you are using python 3.9+ locally, and the remote machine is using python 3.8 (see the traceback you posted).  The `Annotated` class was added to the `typing` module in python 3.9... hence the error when `dill` expects to find it in `typing`.